# Why is the width of cell in UItableview not same as width of screen in simulator?

Tags: swift, uitableview

The table cell is running shorter than it is supposed to be. (I use different background colour which shows difference width) The setting of cell is custom (only row height is change to 140). The playerCell class has nothing but some IBoutlets. Thanks.

(image: storyboard

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count: Int
    if playerBank.count == 0
    {
        count = 1
    }
    else{
        count = playerBank.count
    }

    return count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! playerCell


    if playerBank.isEmpty{
        let p = Player()
       playerBank = setInvalidPlayer(pBank: p, userInput: userInputPlayerName)

    }


    let playerInBank: Player = playerBank[indexPath.row]

        passImageUrl = cell.setPlayerCell(p: playerInBank)
        urlBank.append(passImageUrl)

    let bgColorView = UIView()
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    myIndex = indexPath.row
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowPlayerInfo", sender: self)
    }
}
```

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: How did you set up your layout exactly? It look like you simply dragged the view so it covers the screen in Interface Builder and then ran the app on a simulator with a different screen size.

Comment: I agree. Try to use auto layouts to make everything fit in a more dynamic way. Also you can give the cell itself a background color instead of using a view for it. Another possibility is that your table itself doesn't fill the whole width. Try to debug to see what the real problem is first: https://medium.com/@dmytro.anokhin/overview-of-developer-tools-for-ui-debugging-122e4995f972

Comment: donnywals thanks, but I did not implement any view in my cell. It is just three images and one label. And I don't think it can cover up my width since they are png images. (at least they can not cover up my cell's background colour)

Comment: Departamento B Thanks, but the width of cell is supposed to be auto sizing. I did not touch anything of it.

Comment: @bussmind I think you didn't understand the comments right. You have to set the constraints for your table view itself.

Comment: Retterdesdialogs Thanks, you are absolutely right. Can you post an answer ? I can upvote your solution.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that, while you have a custom cell with custom outlets, that there are no layout constraints in place. So the items that you put into the storyboard are retaining their intrinsic values and not adapting to the device screen size.

If you add constraints to those outlets, especially enough to where the width of the cell can be determined based on the rest of the elements, then your cell should display full width.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out I forgot to give a constraints to my tableview. Thank you again!

Comment: @buzzmind, If this solved your problem, please mark this as the answer.